# Aframe + vuejs - core:schema:warn Unknown property `color` for component/system `undefined`. +10ms aframe.js:327

Tags: javascript, vue.js, aframe

I'm trying to get Aframe and vuejs to work well with each other, however the console is returning warning messages. I'm guessing this is due to aframe checking the attribute values before vue gets a chance to change them.

**Warning messages**

```
core:schema:warn Unknown property `color` for component/system `undefined`. +349ms 2aframe.js:327
core:schema:warn Unknown property `color` for component/system `undefined`. +2ms aframe.js:327
core:schema:warn Unknown property `color` for component/system `undefined`. +1ms aframe.js:327
core:schema:warn Unknown property `height` for component/system `undefined`. +1ms aframe.js:327
core:schema:warn Unknown property `color` for component/system `undefined`. +1s aframe.js:327
```

Here is the code:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <a-scene>
        <test-component v-for="block in blocks" :color="block.color" :position="block.pos"></test-component>
        <a-box :color="color" height="4"></a-box>
        <a-entity position="0 0 10" camera look-controls></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</template>

<script>
import TestComponent from './TestComponent.vue';
require('aframe');

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components:{
        TestComponent,
    },
    data(){
        return {
            color: 'green',
            blocks: [
                {color: 'red', pos: "1 0 0"},
                {color: 'orange', pos: "2 0 0"},
                {color: 'yellow', pos: "3 0 0"}
            ]
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        //test to see if a-frame updates properly
        let that = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            that.blocks.push({color: 'lime', pos: "4 0 0"})
        }, 1000)
        setTimeout(function(){
            that.blocks[3].pos = "5 0 0"
        }, 2000)
    }
}
</script>
```

**TestComponent.vue**

```
<template lang="html">
    <a-box :color="color" :position="position"></a-box>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['color','position'],
}
</script>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>aframetest</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: You need to simplify things. You can get Vue and A-Frame working nicely if you follow the KISS principle then build up from there: https://jsfiddle.net/thoragio/br67aL5a/

Comment: Thanks for your comment @thoragio, much appreciated. You have a good point I could simplify things a bit.

I did notice though that your fiddle is actually changing the DOM directly. This kind of goes against Vue's ethos in that it should be data that you change not the dom.

Never the less I'll simplify my setup a bit and see what happens.

Comment: No worries @jammer, and I take your point about direct manipulation of the DOM. I don't think it is possible to manipulate A-Frame entities directly via Vue without some kind of serialization layer that bridges the two. See Kevin's `aframe-react` for an example: https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-react

Comment: Hey @jammer, for fun and curiosity I got a [basic Vue project](https://github.com/thoragio/aframe-in-vuejs) going that renders an A-Frame scene. This at least proves (to me) that they can work together. I saw similar errors to yours until I included the entire `a-scene` within the `script` block.

Answer (score 0):

working code with simpler setup:
( vuejs 2.4.4 + aframe 0.6.1 )

https://jsfiddle.net/jg6uhh21/

html:

```
<a-scene id="app">
  <test-component v-for="block in blocks" :color="block.color" :position="block.pos"></test-component>
  <a-entity position="0 0 10" camera look-controls></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

javascript:

```
Vue.component('test-component', {
  props: ['color','position'],
  template: `<a-box :color="color" :position="position"></a-box>`
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      blocks: [
        {color: 'red', pos: "1 0 0"},
        {color: 'orange', pos: "2 0 0"},
        {color: 'yellow', pos: "3 0 0"}
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.blocks.push({color: 'lime', pos: "4 0 0"})
    }, 1000)
    setTimeout(() =>{
      this.blocks[3].pos = "5 0 0"
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

small interactive demo I build combining vue.js and aframe in the same way:
https://rawgit.com/frederic-schwarz/aframe-vuejs-3dio/master/index.html
https://github.com/frederic-schwarz/aframe-vuejs-3dio/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this same issue and I game across this [demo](https://github.com/frederic-schwarz/aframe-vuejs-3dio/blob/master/index.html) on GitHub

The part that I was missing was

```js
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'a-scene',
  'a-entity',
  'a-camera',
  'a-box'
]
```

I'm a little new to Vue and I had no idea that `Vue.config.ignoredElements` existed. I added this to my main.js and added all the aframe primitives that I'm using.